# Python Pandas drop row duplicates on a column if no duplicate on other column

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, drop

I have this df with email headers. I need to eliminate all duplicates where **Subject** is the same AND **Source** is different. I have spent hours trying to figure out a solution or find a similar case...

| Date | From | Subject | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/06/21 | Sender1 | Test123 | Inbox |
| 12/06/21 | Sender2 | Confirm | Inbox |
| 12/06/21 | Sender1 | Test123 | Sent |
| 12/06/21 | Sender3 | Test_on | Inbox |
| 12/06/21 | Sender3 | Test_on | Inbox |

Practically from the table above the rows with subject = 'Test123' should be dropped.

| Date | From | Subject | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/06/21 | Sender2 | Confirm | Inbox |
| 12/06/21 | Sender3 | Test_on | Inbox |
| 12/06/21 | Sender3 | Test_on | Inbox |

Comment: something like `df[df['Subject'].duplicated(keep=False) & ~df['Source'].duplicated(keep=False)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set` to determine for each sender if there are multiple source. If yes, drop the row.

```
>>> df.loc[df.groupby('From')['Source'].transform(lambda x: len(set(x)) == 1)]

       Date     From  Subject Source
1  12/06/21  Sender2  Confirm  Inbox
3  12/06/21  Sender3  Test_on  Inbox
4  12/06/21  Sender3  Test_on  Inbox
```

Comment: And it works... Thank you Corralien!

Answer (score 0):

```
duplicated_subject = df.duplicated('Subject', keep=False)
duplicated_subject_and_source = df.duplicated(['Subject', 'Source'], keep=False)
df[~duplicated_subject | duplicated_subject_and_source]
```

eliminate all duplicates where "Subject is the same AND Source is different"

is equivalent to

keep where "Subject is not duplicated OR Subject is duplicated and Source is the same"